# "env: /usr/bin/locale: No such file or directory" in Cmder on startup

Tags: cmder

I had reinstalled Windows and brought down a new version of Cmder and started noticing this message when I start it up:

```
env: /usr/bin/locale: No such file or directory
```

I'd like to know what I can do to fix it.

Cmder is also taking longer to start than it used to for some reason.

## Code

I looked in the code and found this script which looks for that folder related to a Git check:

https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/blob/master/vendor/init.bat#L279

I have Git installed in my system so I don't know what else I'd need to do to get this working.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have the same error as in Cmder bug report #1956
[Git detection should use env from git install root](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/1956).

The analysis of the problem by the author of the report says:

> The reason the error is raised on my system (and Jorg's apparently), is that there is an `env.exe` in my path which does not automatically translates `/usr/bin/locale` to a "locale.exe somewhere my path". My `env.exe` actually tries to execute `/usr/bin/locale`, and as `/usr/bin/locale` does not exist, it raises the error. The issue is really about that the script assumes `env` works like the git provided env, and that assumption is broken on some systems, and it causes an error that is hard for users to fix.

Check the order of items in PATH and ensure that the right `env` is called.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, because earlier I installed "GitHub Desktop", then I installed `cmdermini` using `chocolatey`. The fact is that, the `cmder` determines the installed `git` because installed "GitHub Desktop", you can check it with `where env` command, the output is approximately:

```
"C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-1.6.2\resources\app\git\usr\bin\env.exe"
```

(Possibly you have not installed "GitHub Desktop", but another cut version of `git`.)

But in this directory some files are missing, in particular "locale.exe". `cmdred` at startup performs the task described in `init.bat`, and there is a section for localization where the file locale.exe is use. `cmder` does not find file, and rightly informs you about this.

There are different ways to solve this problem.

- As an example, you can install the full `git` on a virtual machine and simply copy the file `locale.exe` from

`"C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin"`

to your directory

```
C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-1.6.2\resources\app\git\usr\bin.
```

The main thing is that the `git` bitness matches (e.g. 64 on your and virtual machine).

- Alternatively, you can install another version of `git` using e.g. `chocolatey` and edit the system variable PATH, so that cmder will use it.
- Or edit the start task `cmder`, having tried to disable locale.exe search `in init.bat`.
- Maybe you can install full version `cmder` wich include `git` inside.